# R / latticist error - does latticist work on Windows 7 64?

Tags: r

I am trying to use latticist with R 3.0.1 or R studio 0.97.551 on windows 7 64 bit
I am using the standard R library locations.  I have updated all my packages.

I am sometimes able to get some plots with latticist (except points never show up in splom plots), but latticist keeps crashing.  If I am using R studio, R studio shuts down.  If I am using R, the R does not always crash. I have also tried using latticist from rattle.  Usually no error messages.

I have carefully uninstalled and reinstalled R and R studio, cleaning up files in between.  I haven't found any mention of a problem on internet.  Is it windows 64?  Any suggestions on where to look for the cause?

Comment: What is the offending  code you're using? Can you make a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example